# Android Studio / Kotlin - invalid error "Overriding method should call super"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have a `BaseActivity` class which is extended by a `ContainerActivity` class. Because I want to use `BaseActivity` in several other projects I moved it to an Android library that I added as a gradle dependency to these other projects. Other than moving the Base class, no code has changed in the classes extending it. However all of them now have errors on override methods where the super method is annotated with `@CallSuper`. The subclasses are still calling the super method. I can also compile and run the project without problem.

Here is an image of the error message.
[image]

Here is an image where you can see I am in fact calling the super method. (Removed additional code from onCreate)
[image]

Here is the BaseActivity
[image]

Has anyone found a solution to get the IDE to recognize this is not an error?

---

Update:

I added an application module to my project of libraries. They too have the same errors. Looks like anything including a library will show the error if they extend a method from that library annotated with `@CallSuper`

Comment: I filed a bug here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68973255

Comment: and here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67035929

Comment: It's been 2 years now. Any solution so far?

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar issue went away with a new version of android studio some time ago

Answer (score -2):

Have you try to restart or invalidate your IDE cache ?

Comment: I have wrote the same code in my IDE and it working, No warning. Can you show me import section of your classes

Comment: Yes it works until you move the BaseActivity into a separate Library Module. Then add the module as a dependency and extend the class in another project.

Comment: Which Android studio version are you on?

Comment: Android Studio 2.3.3
Build #AI-162.4069837, built on June 6, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b06 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Comment: Android Studio 3.0 Beta 6
Build #AI-171.4333198, built on September 13, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.12.6

Comment: @DavidZafrani looks like an issue starting v3.0